# Ruby on Rails 'find' and its return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

Should be an easy question, but I couldn't find anything on SO about it, so I'm just throwing mine out there:

```
thing_i_use = Thing.find(params[:id])
```

As it stands, in the event that there is no Thing with params[:id], the website defaults to a development page with stack tracing, etc., claiming that there is no thing with ID=etc.

What I'm wondering is how to test against this such that thing_i_use is nil if the params[:id] doesn't exist, or is the object itself.  Basically, using the non-existence of the object in my logic later on in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace:

```
thing_i_use = Thing.find(params[:id])
```

With:

```
thing_i_use = Thing.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

The latest won't spit any error if `id` doesn't exist or is `nil`.

`thing_i_use` will only be `nil`, this will be the only test to do.

Comment: Like a charm.  Thanks for humoring my RoR newbiness.  Now to figure out the rest of it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want `nil` returned if the object with that ID doesn't exist, you can use:

```
thing = Thing.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

If you want to test if it exists (and get true/false):

```
Thing.exists?(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

`thing_i_use = Thing.find(params[:id]) rescue nil`

Comment: 1) `rescue nil`is one of the well known anti patterns 2)`rescue`costs in performance